# How to remove style from styleUrl in component Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

Here is my component

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-pages-landing',
templateUrl: './pages-landing.component.html',
styleUrls:['../../assets/pages-landing/main.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

I import file css of this component by stylesUrls it gen style to head element
 [image]

When i change component. This style still remain and next component load style from previous component. How i can remove it. I want each component have separate style

Comment: If you want each component to have a separate style, don't set `ViewEncapsulation` to `None`

Comment: if i dont set it will not get style from styleURL

Comment: What makes you say that? It certainly should work, as per this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esecxz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: i don't know why with me it not work. This style gen to head element but no thing is applied in html

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] on StackBlitz.com or something please? That way we can try and figure out why it's not working. At the very least, include the relevant CSS

Answer (score 0):

Forget about **encapsulation** in your case, it can't help you with your requirement. Instead, use a shared service, let us call it style-service, which will add/remove the style nodes in the document head.

Instead of adding your CSS styles in the **stylesUrls** of the @**Component** decorator, you will add them by using the style-service on **ngOnInit** function, which will add the style node to the document head. Once the component gets destroyed on **ngOnDestroy** function, you will remove the style by using the style-service, which will remove the style node from the document head.

Enough said, lets see some code:

***style.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StyleService {
  private stylesMap: Map<any, Node> = new Map();
  private host: Node;

  constructor() {
    this.host = document.head;
  }

  private createStyleNode(content: string): Node {
    const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
    styleEl.textContent = content;
    return styleEl;
  }

  addStyle(key: any, style: string): void {
    const styleEl = this.createStyleNode(style);
    this.stylesMap.set(key, styleEl);
    this.host.appendChild(styleEl);
  }

  removeStyle(key: any): void {
    const styleEl = this.stylesMap.get(key);
    if (styleEl) {
      this.stylesMap.delete(key);
      this.host.removeChild(styleEl);
    }
  }
}
```

**PageLandingComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

import { StyleService } from '../style.service';

declare const require: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pages-landing',
  templateUrl: './pages-landing.component.html',
  styleUrls:[],//remove CSS from here
})
export class PageLandingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private styleService: StyleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.styleService.addStyle('main', require('../../assets/pages-landing/main.css'));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.styleService.removeStyle('main');
  }

}
```